# How can I draw an arc using PIL?

Tags: python, geometry, python-imaging-library

I get how to draw a circle, but not an arc

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

img = Image.new("RGB",(60,60),'white')
dr = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
dr.ellipse((0,0,60,60),'yellow','black')
```

Now I get it, thanks for the help..

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

image = Image.new('RGB',(90,90),'white')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.ellipse((0,0,90,90),'yellow','blue')
draw.ellipse((25,20,35,30),'yellow','blue')
draw.ellipse((50,20,60,30),'yellow','blue')
draw.arc((20,40,70,70), 0, 180, 0) #draw circle in black
image.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Use the [`PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.arc()`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.arc) function.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad to hear you're making progress after my comment. However I'm not completely sure that you've "got it"...since there's no need for that `box=(1, 1, 90, 90)` statement before the `draw.arc()` call—`box` being an unused variable that has no effect on the image or anything else, so might as well be removed because it's a distraction and its creation only slows things down ever so slightly.

Although it may be inconsequential, but you should probably also make the outermost (first) ellipse drawn slightly smaller, so it will lay completely *within* the 90x90 pixel image (pixels in an image that size will have x and y coordinates values from 0 to 89). The way you're doing it, the bottom-most and rightmost pixels of this ellipse are getting cut-off.

To illustrate what I mean, here's an (enlarged) version of the image the code now at the end of your question produces:

[image: OP's image enlarged]

---

Below is the same code with these minor corrections applied, and under that the slightly different image that it produces:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

image = Image.new('RGB', (90, 90), 'white')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.ellipse((0, 0, 89, 89), 'yellow', 'blue')  # made this a little smaller..
draw.ellipse((25, 20, 35, 30), 'yellow', 'blue')
draw.ellipse((50, 20, 60, 30), 'yellow', 'blue')
draw.arc((20, 40, 70, 70), 0, 180, 'black')  # draw an arc in black
image.show()
```

Improved result:

[image: Image resulting from my changes (enlarged)]

Comment: Thanks, you're advice is great!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot, so I made some changes following your perfect advices:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

image = Image.new('RGB',(91,91),'white') # background image
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image) # this makes you draw on image
draw.ellipse((0,0,90,90),'yellow','blue') # face
draw.ellipse((25,20,35,30),'yellow','blue') # left eye
draw.ellipse((50,20,60,30),'yellow','blue') # right eye
draw.arc((20,40,70,70), 0, 180, 0) # smile
image.show()
```

Now the image is perfectly fit in the middle of the background:

[image]

And here there are a couple of detail on the image that have been added:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

image = Image.new('RGB',(91,91),'blue')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.ellipse((0,0,90,90),'yellow','blue') # face
draw.ellipse((25,20,35,30),'yellow','blue') # left eye
draw.ellipse((28,25,32,30),'blue','blue') # left ...
draw.ellipse((50,20,60,30),'yellow','blue') # right eye
draw.ellipse((53,25,58,30),'blue','blue') # right ...
draw.arc((40,50,50,55), 0, 360, 0) # nose
draw.arc((20,40,70,70), 0, 180, 0) # smile
image.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you've got the hang of it (learned the proper way of doing it). Please consider accepting my answer, since it and my original comment under your question were what got you to the point you're at.

Comment: thank you Martineau, I also added some text to the picture, I will add it here, maybe, as I have them posted also here: [my python blog](https://pythonprogs.blogspot.com/2017/01/watermarking-images-pil.html)

Answer (score 0):

As I was saying in a comment, I added some code to the previous one, also checking some other answers in stackoverflow:

```
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw,ImageFont

# sample text and font
unicode_text = u"SMILE WORLD!" # This is used to shape the image around the text size
font = ImageFont.truetype("consola.ttf", 28, encoding="unic")
font2 = ImageFont.truetype("consola.ttf", 10, encoding="unic")
# get the line size
text_width, text_height = font.getsize(unicode_text)

# create a blank canvas with extra space between lines
# I added 100 to host the image and 30 for the watermark length
canvas = Image.new('RGB', (text_width + 30, text_height + 100), "orange")

# draw the text onto the text canvas, and use black as the text color
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(canvas)
draw.text((5,5), unicode_text, 'blue', font) # This paste the unicode_text=u"SMILE WORLD"

def smile(x=30,y=30):
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(canvas)
    draw.ellipse((0+x,0+y,90+x,90+y),'yellow','blue') # face
    draw.ellipse((25+x,20+y,35+x,30+y),'yellow','blue') # left eye
    draw.ellipse((28+x,25+y,32+x,30+y),'blue','blue') # left ...
    draw.ellipse((50+x,20+y,60+x,30+y),'yellow','blue') # right eye
    draw.ellipse((53+x,25+y,58+x,30+y),'blue','blue') # right ...
    draw.arc((40+x,50+y,50+x,55+y), 0, 360, 0) # nose
    draw.arc((20+x,40+y,70+x,70+y), 0, 180, 0) # smile

smile(60,28)    
draw.text((5,100), u'This image is covered by copyright', 'blue', font2)
draw.text((5,110), u'pythonprogramming.altervista.org', 'blue', font2)
canvas.show()
canvas.save("smile.png")
```

And I get this:

[image]